# How to create text view dynamically for each row of list

Tags: android

I am currently developing an Android application and it is receiving cities around me data from the server and populating the listview. I need to show weather data in a text view for each city in the list view. The problem is making text view dynamically for each city when it is loaded into the list view. How do I create tetx view dynamically for each city and how do I determine for 'x' cities, I need 'x' textviews.

Comment: If you want you can create it dynamically. But having and XML generated row is much easier. DO you still want to create it dynamically?

Comment: Yeah i want to create dynamically for each city

Answer (score 1):

You can create for each city by extending BaseAdapter class:

```
private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return myList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setText(getItem(position).weatherData);
            return textView;
        }
    }
```

Also you are free to use `LayoutInflater` and `ViewHolder` pattern.